# How to know which checkbox is checked from a expandable list view and get its info(Android)

Tags: android, sql, checkbox, expandablelistview

I'm working on an app for Android and I'm stuck, I already made a expandable list where its children are checkboxes. This activity gets its info from a sql database the only problem is that I don't know how to get which checkboxes were selected after the confirm button is pushed.

I mean all I want is to get the text or id of every checkbox that was checked so I can make an array and then put that information on a table in the database.

Here is my activity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ManualQuestionnerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    /*Variable de la Base de Datos*/
    protected DBHelper _db_helper;
    protected SQLiteDatabase _db;
    protected ExpandableListView _expandableList_seccion;
    protected Button _button_confirm;
    protected CheckBox _checkbox_child;
    int _id_company, _id_branch, _id_area,_id_subarea,_id_type,_id_questionner;
    String _string_timestarter;
    
    
    
    /**/
    private ExpandListAdapter _expandList_Adapter;
    private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> _expandList_Items;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manual_questionner);
        
        Intent i = getIntent();

        /*inicializando las variables con valores de la base de datos*/
        _id_company = i.getIntExtra("company", 0);
        _id_branch = i.getIntExtra("branch", 0);
        _id_area = i.getIntExtra("area", 0);
        _id_subarea = i.getIntExtra("subarea", 0);
        _id_type = i.getIntExtra("type", 0);
        _id_questionner = i.getIntExtra("questionner", 0);
        _string_timestarter = i.getStringExtra("inicio");
        
        
        
        _expandableList_seccion = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.manual_questionner_expandablelistview);
        _button_confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.manual_questionner_button_confirm);
        
        _button_confirm.setOnClickListener(this);
        _checkbox_child = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
        //Log.w("LLEEEEEGOOOOOO", Integer.toString(seriesId));
        
        /*Creando la BD*/
        try
        {
            _db_helper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
            _db_helper.createDataBase();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FAVOR DE CONTACTAR AL ADMINISTRADOR: error_#000", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        
        /*Se abre la Base de Datos*/
        try 
        {
            _db_helper.openDataBase();
            _db = _db_helper.getReadableDatabase(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FAVOR DE CONTACTAR AL ADMINISTRADOR: error_#001", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        
        
        
     
        
        
        _expandList_Items = SetStandardGroups();//llenando la expandable list
        _expandList_Adapter = new ExpandListAdapter(ManualQuestionnerActivity.this, _expandList_Items);
        _expandableList_seccion.setAdapter(_expandList_Adapter);
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> SetStandardGroups() {
         
            final String [] ia ={"ia"};
            Cursor cursor_seccion = _db.query("i", ia, "ib = '" + _id_questionner + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor_seccion.moveToFirst();
            
            
            
            
                        
            
            
            ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> list = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
            
            
            
           
          
           do{
               
                ArrayList<ExpandListChild> list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

                ExpandListGroup gru1 = new ExpandListGroup();

                gru1.setName(cursor_seccion.getString(0));
                /*temas*/
                final String [] _id = {"_id"};
                Cursor cursor_seccion_id = _db.query("i", _id, "ia = '"+cursor_seccion.getString(0)+"'", null,null,null,null,"1");
                cursor_seccion_id.moveToFirst();
                
                int value = Integer.parseInt(cursor_seccion_id.getString(0));
                
                /*preguntas*/
                final String[] ja = {"ja"};
                Cursor cursor_question = _db.query("j",ja,"jb = '"+value+"'",null,null,null,null,null);
                cursor_question.moveToFirst();
                
                
            
                
                Log.w("HOLAAAAAA",Integer.toString(cursor_question.getCount()));
                
                Log.w("HOLAAAAAA",cursor_question.getString(0));
                
                
                do
                {
                    ExpandListChild ch1_1 = new ExpandListChild();
                    ch1_1.setName(cursor_question.getString(0));//
                    ch1_1.setTag(null);
                    list2.add(ch1_1);

                    
                    
                }while(cursor_question.moveToNext());

                gru1.setItems(list2);

                
               
                
                list.add(gru1);
                
                
                
                
                
           }while(cursor_seccion.moveToNext());
            
            
            return list;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.manual_questionner, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) 
    {
        if(_checkbox_child.isChecked() == true)
        {
        Log.w("SE PUSHOOOOO",":D");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.w("SE DESPUCHOOOOOOO","D:");
        }
    }
*/


    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId()== R.id.manual_questionner_button_confirm)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guardando Datos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent home = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(home);

        }
        
        
    }

    
    
    
}
```

And here is my expandable list activity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> grupos;
    
    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> grupos)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.grupos = grupos;
    }
    
    public void addItem(ExpandListChild item, ExpandListGroup group)
    {
        if(!grupos.contains(group))
        {
            grupos.add(group);
        }
        int index = grupos.indexOf(group);
        
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> ch = grupos.get(index).getItems();
        ch.add(item);
        
        grupos.get(index).setItems(ch);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> chList = grupos.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        
        
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        
        if(view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
        }
        
        CheckBox tv = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
        tv.setText(child.getName().toString());
        tv.setTag(child.getTag());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<ExpandListChild> chList = grupos.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return grupos.get(groupPosition);  
         }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return grupos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
         ExpandListGroup group = (ExpandListGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
         
         if(view == null)
         {
             LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             view = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_group_item, null);
         }
         
         TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
            tv.setText(group.getName());

        
        
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    enter code here
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold the checkbox values in a hashmap.

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> grupos;
    HashMap<String, Boolean> mCheckBoxData = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        .....
}
```

In your getChildView function set a CheckedChange listener on the checkbox and put the check box tag and its value to the hashmap.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater infalInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
    }

    CheckBox checkBoxChild = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_child);
    checkBoxChild.setText(child.getName().toString() );
    checkBoxChild.setTag(child.getTag());


    checkBoxChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean value) {
            mCheckBoxData.put(child.getTag(), value);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

// ExpandListAdapter's getCheckBoxData method 
public HashMap<String, Boolean> getCheckBoxData(){
    return mCheckBoxData;
}
```

Confirm button :

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId()== R.id.manual_questionner_button_confirm)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guardando Datos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Intent home = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        //startActivity(home);
        HashMap<String, Boolean> checkBoxData = _expandList_Adapter.getCheckBoxData();

        // Get the keys  
        Set<String> keys = checkBoxData.keySet();  

        for (String key : keys) {
            Log.d("LOG", key + "=" + checkBoxData.get(key));  
        }  
    }

}
```