# Get checkbox value from expandableview

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview, hashset

I know similar question asked before, but they don't solve my problem.

I am creating a check box expandable view whose data is coming from some Api. Now I want all selected check box value in my activity.

I am getting all values (I refer another question [Expandable check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501933/how-to-know-wich-checkbox-is-checked-from-a-expandable-list-view-and-get-its-inf)) and I got this value as return(`[Pair{4 4}, Pair{3 3}, Pair{0 0}, Pair{3 6}, Pair{1 5}, Pair{3 7}, Pair{4 3}, Pair{3 4}, Pair{1 6}, Pair{4 2}, Pair{3 5}]`). Now how could I get value from this value ?

```
  private final Set<Pair<Long, Long>> mCheckedItems = new HashSet<Pair<Long, Long>>();
```

And

```
 public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_group_child, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.expandableChild);

    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childCkBox);
    // add tag to remember groupId/childId
    final Pair<Long, Long> tag = new Pair<Long, Long>(
            getGroupId(groupPosition),
            getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));

    cb.setTag(tag);
    // set checked if groupId/childId in checked items
    cb.setChecked(mCheckedItems.contains(tag));
    // set OnClickListener to handle checked switches
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            final Pair<Long, Long> tag = (Pair<Long, Long>) v.getTag();
            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                mCheckedItems.add(tag);
                //mCheckBoxData.put(getGroupId(groupPosition),
                        getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));
            } else {
                mCheckedItems.remove(tag);
                //mCheckBoxData.remove(getGroupId(groupPosition),getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));
            }
        }
    });

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}
```

In Activity:

```
  private Set<Pair<Long, Long>> mCheckedItems = new HashSet<Pair<Long, Long>>();
  mCheckedItems = listAdapter.getCheckedItems();
  System.out.println(mCheckedItems);
```

I know now how to retrieve data from this type.

### Edit

I have multiple group and all data is coming through Api.

Comment: you can use interface for that..

Comment: @gaurang How to use that.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

create interface AdapterCallback.java

```
interface AdapterCallback {
    void onMethodCallback(int pos, String name);
}
```

in your adapter

```
    private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;
//constructor
 public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataClass> arrayList, AdapterCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.mAdapterCallback = callback;
    }
```

in your get view method call where you check/ uncheck checkbox

```
mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback(rowItem.getPos(), rowItem.getName());
```

in your activity implement interface like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterCallback
```

and override your interface method in to your activity like this

```
@Override
    public void onMethodCallback(int pos, String name) {
        Log.d("interface", "calling");
        Log.d("pos", ""+pos);
        Log.d("name", name);

    }
```

Comment: I will try that. But I am getting value from adapter but I cant retrieve that value. Could you hemp me out. `[Pair{4 4}, Pair{3 3}, Pair{0 0}, Pair{3 6}, Pair{1 5}, Pair{3 7}, Pair{4 3}, Pair{3 4}, Pair{1 6}, Pair{4 2}, Pair{3 5}]`

Comment: differentiate that pair from your adapter and send the data (which you want in your activity) to the activity with the help of interface

Comment: I have different groups in expandable view and all groups contain check box. So I need value in pair.

Comment: you can refer more about expandable list here http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/

Comment: accept the answer if your problem related to this question is sovled, so that others can get help from this.

Comment: Hey what is `public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataClass> arrayList, AdapterCallback callback)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154990/discussion-between-gaurang-and-vivek).